# Error - Connect-SPOService : Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, error

I'm trying to connect to SharePoint online tenant using the below PowerShell script but I get the error:

I'm sure the script is correct because it works fine on other machines. But on one particular machine where I'm supposed to work, i get this error:

```
Connect-SPOService : Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.
At line:6 char:1
 + Connect-SPOService -Url https://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential 
 $userC ...
     
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-SPOService], MissingMethodException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.MissingMethodException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.ConnectSPOService
```

#Connect to SharePoint Online Script

```
$adminUPN="User Email Address"
$orgName="Tenant"
$userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Type the password."
Connect-SPOService -Url https://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $userCredential
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()' is related to .NET Framework 4.6 not installed correctly, please refer the similiar question here:

[Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253747/method-not-found-0-system-array-empty)

You can download and install .NET Framework 4.6 here:

[Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.2 (Offline Installer)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53344)